# Slated__ Open SSL with line Feed? and a Password Instruction?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, salt

Well am just a noob here but had been really interested in cryptography.  Found this code somewhere and took it as a challenge with no luck! any idea what it is implying?

echo "U2FsdGVkX1+ZSnXut5eBy0fyGxbTVAVuSJl7jj3HxAiE2SdfvWsOSGO6c38XMt9C\nT2IXIg0jHiV0O7nwR6dEFg==" > t; openssl enc -pass pass:[1JTMmXW-privkey-hex] -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in t

Answer (score 1):

It's a decryption of a ciphertext given in Base64 and a password.

Comment: The first part translates to "Salted__" what I can't figure out is : 1- The Expected Password  ( is that a salt  ascii there or just a raw password that must be hashed?"  2- is "t" an output file name ? oh wait that's three  3- shall I remove the "'\n" from the string? am sorry am relatively new to cryptography